# getting this error while importing package in go any idea how to resolve this?

Tags: go, import, package

When I run the following:

```sh
go get github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers/volume
```

It prints:

```sh
 github.com/docker/go-connections/sockets

../github.com/docker/go-connections/sockets/sockets.go:35:26: dialer.DialContext undefined (type proxy.Dialer has no field or method DialContext)

../github.com/docker/go-connections/sockets/sockets_unix.go:24:28: undefined: context
```

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: go version go1.12.5 linux/amd64

Comment: The errors are correct, and that code is simply broken.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [proxy.Dialer](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy#Dialer) whereas it seems you want [net.Dialer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer), as that one has a [`DialContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer.DialContext).

Answer (score 0):

For those not familiar with go (like me), a very temporary workaround (until there is a fix for https://github.com/docker/go-connections/issues/60) would be:

```
cd ~/go/src/github.com/docker/go-connections
git checkout 9885905e989f4d8cc9f42d3549c5be9c27e4460d
go get github.com/docker/go-connections/sockets
cd -
```

Cheers